# How to display all the unix commands available on the system?

Tags: osx, zsh, executable

I'm reading a book, `Learning Unix for OS X by Dave Taylor`. It says:

> To quickly see all of the binary executables—Unix programs—on your
>   system,
>
> Open the Terminal, hold down the `Shift` key, and press `Esc-?`,
>   or press `Control-X` followed by `Shift-1` (using `Shift-1` to get an
>   exclamation mark).
>
> Before the commands are displayed in the Terminal,
>   however, you’ll first be prompted (asked) to make a choice:
>
> ```
> $ 
> Display all 1453 possibilities? (y or n)
> ```
>
> If you press the `n` key on your keyboard, you’ll be taken back to a command prompt and nothing else will happen. However, if you press the `y` key, you’ll see a multi-column list of Unix commands stream past in the Terminal window.

However, the problem is, when I hold down `Shift` key and press `Esc-?` nothing happens. Same for Pressing `Control-X` followed by `Shift-1`. What am I doing wrong? Is there any setting that I need to enable before using this feature? I'm using iTerm2 on Mac El Capitan. It doesn't work on the stock terminal either. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to press `<TAB>` twice. Result should be the same.

Comment: @YogeshUmeshVaity No, you don't have to type `!`. Just press the `Tab` twice. You can also type whatever you want, then press the `Tab` twice and it'll print only commands starting with what you typed.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Just pressing `Tab` twice is doing nothing on my terminal. It only prints 4 spaces. However, typing some letter and pressing `Tab` twice does print commands starting with that letter, that's nice. Thank a lot.

Comment: @Thomas: tab completion on an empty command line is shell-dependent. (My `zsh` doesn't seem to do it; neither does my `bash` here, but it did like `C-x !`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instructions in the book are for bash. Zsh is a different program with different key bindings.

In zsh, you can see a list of all commands (external, builtin, function, alias even keywords...) with:

```
type -m '*'
```

For just their names:

```
whence -wm '*' | sed 's/:[^:]*$//'
```

Or for the names of external commands only:

```
print -rlo -- $commands:t | less
```

[`$commands`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-commands) is an array that contains all external commands. The [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `:t` truncates the directory part of the command paths (keeps only the **t**ail). `print -rlo` to print them **r**aw in alphabetical **o**rder, one per **l**ine.

Longer, but less cryptic:

```
for p in "$path[@]"; do (cd ${p:-.} && ls); done | sort -u | less
```

This can be adjusted to work in any sh-style shell:

```
(IFS=:; for p in $PATH; do (cd ${p:-.} && ls); done) | sort -u | less
```

(All the commands I list here assume that there are no “unusual” characters in command paths.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between zsh and bash. I did have feeling that it must have something to do with shell. I tested the commands specified in question with bash and they do work well.

Comment: I was about to comment that this is not equivalent to what I see when completing since it includes files from PATH which are not executable. But then I checked and realize that ZSH does *not* filter out non-executable files(!). I assume this is due to performance, but I have an old script which does this and it run sin 0.05s on my system... not that it's that useful to have lots on non-executable files in PATH, but its 2023. Can we have nice things (an option)?

Comment: @olejorgenb This may be due to performance: testing whether a file is executable is slow in some circumstances (mostly, on remote file systems), and this can be noticeable with very large directories. It's not very useful on typical systems, because it's uncommon to have non-executable files in $PATH directories. There is an option `hash_executables_only`; I don't know which of the methods I list it affects.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks for the pointer to `hash_executables_only`. I sometimes use somewhat "ad-hoc" project specific directories in PATH and these can accumulate some junk while I work.

Answer (score 3):

Though pressing `TAB` twice will do the trick as mentioned by Thomas.

But if that didn't work then try this simple yet dirty hack:

```
for i in `echo $PATH | sed 's:\:: :g'`
do
       echo $i
done
```

Later, you can alter the view as per the need/ease.

Comment: The `Tab` trick worked. Your answer is interesting too. I'll remember this for future reference. Have an upvote. Thanks for help.

Comment: The `PATH`-based variant won't list internal commands though (that's a minor quibble). @SHW, perhaps your `sed` command would be easier to read with another separator (`sed 's/:/ /g'`); `tr : \ ` would also do the trick.

Comment: `zsh` already provides `$PATH` as an array in `$path` (like `(t)csh`), you can just do `print -rl -- "${path[@]}"` and `print -rlo -- $^path/*(ND:t)` for the files in there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to answer by @Gilles I figured out that the commands described in the question are for `bash` shell.

### For bash users

So for future visitors, if you are using `bash` shell, refer to the commands described in the question description above to display all the available Unix commands on your system.

### For zsh users

If you are using the `zsh` shell, the correct way to display all commands is:

Type `!` (exclamation character) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice.

That is, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice.

If this doesn't work for you, refer to tricks described by Gilles and SHW in other answers.

Comment: That will not necessarily work depending on how you've configured `zsh` and its completion system. Typing `;` followed by TAB is more likely to work.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The commands I have mentioned, work with default settings of `zsh`. Typing `;` and `Tab` displays the files and directories in the current path.